# Routing configuration to forward multicast traffic to a single NIC on RedHat 6

Tags: linux, redhat, routes, multicast

I'm trying to edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0` to make all multicast packets sent to device eth0 on `RedHat 6.3`, following [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html).

I tried writing like:

```
224.0.0.0/4 dev eth0
```

but it never works....
How can I specify multicast routing on this file?

Comment: try #route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0

Comment: Yeah that command works, but I'd like to persist this configuration on file so that I can reboot the machine..

Comment: One more way is to add above command in /etc/rc.local file. this file will run whatever command inside everytime when system reboot.

Comment: probably you should use same file, but different format? ADDRESS0=224.0.0.0\nNETMASK0=255.0.0.0\nGATEWAY0=ip. it works for me more or less under RHEL 7

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add route in `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes`

One more alternative solution to save permanent route is add your route command in following file.

```
/etc/rc.local
```

- More option to look.

also Enable MC routing in kernel

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding=0
```

Make sure you have MC routing support in kernel. for example.

```
# cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep IP_MROUTE
CONFIG_IP_MROUTE=y
```

Netstat also tell you whether it enable or not

```
netstat -g
```

Comment: Thanks, "I think you should add route in /etc/sysconfig/static-routes" - What should I add??